# Unable to access my sharedpreferences and calculate

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I made an Android app wherein I receive text and numeric (decimal) values from user in 5 different activities then store them in my sharedpreferences. I am able to restore all values using editor(); in all previous 5 activities.

**Now**

In final calculation activity I'm restoring all user input (text and numbers) and storing them in string and double variables. performing calculations in below posted code activity;

**Problem**

I am unable to view results in textview using getText.

Is there anything missing?

```
public class Xcalculateforall extends Activity {

    Button qcbut, coatsolbut;
    TextView TVqcbut, TVcoatsolbut, TVbrand;
    double tdrum, rqctotal;
    String a;
    public static String FILE1 = "MyPrefsFile";
    SharedPreferences abcPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resultmain);

        qcbut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bQCS);
        coatsolbut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCSP);

        TVqcbut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQCS);
        TVbrand = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBrand);
        TVcoatsolbut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCSP);

        abcPref = this.getSharedPreferences(FILE1, 0);

        a = abcPref.getString("tA", ""); //receives text value and store in 'a' String

        double k = Integer.parseInt(abcPref.getString("tsK", ""));
        double l = Integer.parseInt(abcPref.getString("tsL", ""));
        double m = Integer.parseInt(abcPref.getString("tsM", ""));
        double n = Integer.parseInt(abcPref.getString("tsN", ""));
        double o = Integer.parseInt(abcPref.getString("tsO", ""));
        double p = Integer.parseInt(abcPref.getString("tsP", ""));
        tdrum = 20 / m;
        double samv = (tdrum / k) / l;
        double samv2 = (Math.sqrt(samv));
        double tsample = ((samv2 + 1) * k) * l;
        double rmicro = tsample * n;
        double rchem = tsample * o;
        double rother = tsample * p;
        double rinqc = rmicro + rchem + rother;
        rqctotal = rinqc - 2;

        qcbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TVqcbut.setText(rqctotal + "Days");
                TVbrand.setText("" + a);
                // Intent results = new Intent("com.traviss.calculate.RESULT");
                // startActivity(results);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Updating query --- previous activity where i take user input**

```
public class G2J extends Activity {
    Button two2five, save2;

    EditText edtG, edtH, edtI, edtJ, edtK;
    int tG, tH, tI, tJ, tK;
    String tsG, tsH, tsI, tsJ, tsK;
    public static String FileP2 = "MyPrefsFile";
    SharedPreferences abcPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.g2j);
        two2five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btp2);

        edtG = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etG);
        edtH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etH);
        edtI = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etI);
        edtJ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etJ);
        edtK = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etK);

        abcPref = getSharedPreferences(FileP2, 0);
        edtG.setText(abcPref.getString("tsG", ""));
        edtH.setText(abcPref.getString("tsH", ""));
        edtI.setText(abcPref.getString("tsI", ""));
        edtJ.setText(abcPref.getString("tsJ", ""));
        edtK.setText(abcPref.getString("tsK", ""));

        two2five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((!edtG.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtH.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtI.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtJ.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        && (!edtK.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    abcPref = G2J.this.getSharedPreferences(FileP2, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = abcPref.edit();
                    editor.putString("tsG", edtG.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsH", edtH.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsI", edtI.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsJ", edtJ.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("tsK", edtK.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast message = Toast.makeText(G2J.this, "Values are saved", 2000);
                    message.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                    message.show();
                    Intent openl2p = new Intent("com.traviss.calculate.L2P");
                    startActivity(openl2p);
                }
                else {
                    Toast failz = Toast.makeText(G2J.this,
                            "Values are not Entered", 2000);
                    failz.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                    failz.show();
                }
            };
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting values in `l`, `m`, ... ?

Comment: yes shobhit mere ko usme values user se mil rahi hain; shall i try to see wts in tsL???

Comment: ok. How are you sure that you are getting values? Yaa try to `Log` them and see.

Comment: thanks ,,, i have never tried Log can you code them for me.. please

Comment: @monikasingh In your previous activity you have not put the value of `tA`

Comment: its in activity 1 code i posted the activity wherein i get decimal values, and codes used to store values in shared preferences i think they are alright. please help guys

Comment: @monikasingh can you paste where you have  done this `editor.putString("t!", edtA.getText().toString());` ?

Comment: its already there, one more thing i have not declared tsA or any other string in present calculation class.. is that creating any issue???

Comment: @monikasingh declare tsA again in calculation class and try if you get the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your string variables and xml layout

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
int k = Integer.parseInt(abcPref.getString("tsK", ""));
```

Comment: i dont think its gonna work, first i need decimal values second even text of variable 'a' is not displayed. very wiered thing is happening here

Comment: In that case use - `Double.parseDouble(String)`.Are you sure your prefs. value are getting stored?

Comment: I am using same preference in all previous activities and values are getting restored, i dont know if they are passed to different activity; i belive if they are restored on reopening the activity, they are stored and using key values like "tsK" i can read them in different activity. may be i m missing something

Comment: @monikasingh until i see all your classes i cant say whats going wrong

Comment: i am editing my code and data to remove some information once i am done i will post project here can i give only class??

Comment: @monikasingh in the calculation class declare it again and see if you get the value of a

Comment: @monikasingh ya give only class files, that's enough

Comment: @Metalhead1247 are you there??

Comment: @monikasingh  tell me the class names where you get the error

Comment: did you go through class??

Comment: @monikasingh from which class you are moving to?

Comment: as such i didnot get any error, problem relates to -- i am not able to get results out of any variable, even variable 'a' which is string value is not getting displayed in textview..

Comment: result.java is main class were i get data from all pervious 5 activities

Comment: am i getting any data in any of the varibales??

Answer (score 0):

You wont get decimal values using  **Integer.parseInt(String)**

Do this

```
 double k = Double.parseDouble(abcPref.getString("tsK", ""));

  a = String.valueOf(abcPref.getString("tA", ""));
```

Comment: Many thanks for input but why I am not getting string 'a'?? any idea??

Comment: still not getting any text :-(

Comment: @monikasingh paste your project at www.mediafire.com ill debug and give you

Comment: @monikasingh in the calculation class declare it again and see if you get the value of a